# trouble integrating twitter api command in python

Tags: python, api, twitter, syntax-error, tweets

I am trying to implement this into python, but I am having difficulty:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

here is what I have:

```
def reqs():
    t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('...'))
    tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.snl()
    retweetids = t.statuses.retweeted_by(id=str(tweets[0]['id']))    <<does not work.
    print retweetids
```

Comment: what do you mean by does not work ? What is the error you get ?

Comment: @karthikr I get the error:

{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

Comment: @karthikr also, I do not know if I am using it properly

Comment: looks like you are using the old api: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11595

Comment: @karthikr No I am not. If you go here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

you will see this is the latest api (1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
    `retweets`
instead of retweeters